# CSS 'height' value going downwards instead of upwards

Tags: javascript, css, position, height

I am using javascript to generate a simple bar graph. I want to get the bars going up instead of down. How can I do this?

Note that the mainContainer is referencing a div in the HTML and that I am only adding styles with javascript.

```
var sampleData = [2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 3];

var mainContainer = document.querySelector(".graphite-container");

var addColumns = function(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var column = document.createElement("div");
    column.className = "graphite-column";
    column.Id = 'column-' + (i + 1);
    column.innerHTML = column.Id;
    var columnValue = '';
    columnValue += (data[i] * 25) + 'px';
    $(column).css({
      "display": "inline-block",
      "height": columnValue,
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
    $(mainContainer).append(column);
  }
};

addColumns(sampleData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `vertical-align:bottom;` to columns.

```js
var sampleData = [2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 3];

var mainContainer = document.querySelector(".graphite-container");

var addColumns = function(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var column = document.createElement("div");
    column.className = "graphite-column";
    column.Id = 'column-' + (i + 1);
    column.innerHTML = column.Id;
    var columnValue = '';
    columnValue += (data[i] * 25) + 'px';
    $(column).css({
      "display": "inline-block",
      "height": columnValue,
      "background-color": "blue",
      "vertical-align": "bottom"
    });
    $(mainContainer).append(column);
  }
};

addColumns(sampleData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graphite-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

G'day. The origin point for computer displays is the top left corner. It's not the bottom left corner like you're used to. This is probably the root cause of your issue. It's an algorithmic error rather than a programming error.